# How do you run New-AzRoleAssignment in noninteractive mode?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm running the following cmdlet:

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $workspaceid -RoleDefinitionId $roleId -ObjectId $objectid -verbose -debug
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
Powershell is in noninteractive mode.  Read and prompt functionality is unavailable.
```

Fair enough.  So I try running it with the -Force switch, returns error:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches the parameter name "Force".
```

Try with "-confirm:$false", get an error that says:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches the parameter name "confirm".
```

If neither "confirm" nor "force" work, then why is it complaining about being in noninteractive mode?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this Az module's cmdlet doesn't work while executing in the non-interactive mode (for example, by using a pipeline). I managed to overcome this by just toggling to Azure CLI.

Instead of this:
`New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectID -RoleDefinitionId $roleId -Scope $workspaceid`

use this:
`az role assignment create --assignee $objectID --role $roleId --scope $workspaceid`

Note: if you need to assign a role to an application identity (for instance, Databricks), **--assignee** is the **applicationId** from the App registration, non objectID.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below findings help to fix the issue:

- Many workarounds suggesting the same parameters to pass for this kind of error in PowerShell like passing the parameters `-Force` and `-Confirm:$false` to the PowerShell Commands.
- Try including this parameter also for that PowerShell command      e.g., `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature`

Comment: The question states that neither `-Force` nor `-Confirm:$false` are accepted by `New-AzRoleAssignment`